# Excel Workbook Trouble

Tags: vba, excel

Everything is good up until I get to the loop.

Once I get to the loop it runs through it's cycle adjusting the first name and last names into two different columns, but then, for some reason, it gives me an error. I can't figure out why.

Code below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BreakNameApart()
    'declare variables and assign address to Worksheet object variable
    Dim intLocation As Integer, shtConsult As Worksheet, rngCell As Range
    Set shtConsult = _
        Application.Workbooks("Franklin Consultants.xls").Worksheets("Consultants")
    shtConsult.Columns("b").Insert
    shtConsult.Range("a4").Value = "Last Name"
    shtConsult.Range("b4").Value = "First Name"
    shtConsult.Range("a4:b4").Font.Bold = True
    'beginning in cell A5, seperate each full name into last and first name
    Set rngCell = shtConsult.Range("a5")
    Do Until rngCell.Value = ""
        'find location of space
        intLocation = InStr(1, rngCell.Value, " ")
        'assign first name to appropriate cell in column B
        rngCell.Offset(columnoffset:=1).Value = _
                Left(String:=rngCell.Value, Length:=intLocation - 1)
        'assign last name to current cell
        rngCell.Value = Mid(String:=rngCell.Value, Start:=intLocation + 1)
        'assign the address of the cell in the next row to the rngCell variable
        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(rowoffset:=1)
    Loop
   'adjust the width of columns A and B
   shtConsult.Columns("a:b").AutoFit


End Sub
```

---

Most notably it gives me an error here:

```
rngCell.Offset(columnoffset:=1).Value = _
                Left(String:=rngCell.Value, Length:=intLocation - 1)
```

Comment: Have a look at the value of `rngCell` when the error is thrown - if there's no space in the name then `intLocation` will be 0 and the `LEFT` function will try and return -1 characters from `rngCell` causing an error.  Another possible option - any names have a leading space at the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will split the values in column A into Columns A and B (last and first name) :

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BreakNameApart()

    'declare variables and assign address to Worksheet object variable
    Dim intLocation As Integer, shtConsult As Worksheet, rngCell As Range

    Set shtConsult = _
        Application.Workbooks("Franklin Consultants.xls").Worksheets("Consultants")

    shtConsult.Columns("b").Insert
    shtConsult.Range("a4").Value = "Last Name"
    shtConsult.Range("b4").Value = "First Name"
    shtConsult.Range("a4:b4").Font.Bold = True

    'beginning in cell A5, seperate each full name into last and first name
    Set rngCell = shtConsult.Range("a5")

    Do Until rngCell.Value = ""
        'find location of space
        intLocation = InStr(1, rngCell.Value, " ")

        If intLocation > 0 Then ' space found
            'assign first name to appropriate cell in column B
            rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(rngCell.Value, intLocation - 1)

            'assign last name to current cell
            rngCell.Value = Mid(rngCell.Value, intLocation + 1)
        End If
        'assign the address of the cell in the next row to the rngCell variable
        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

   'adjust the width of columns A and B
   shtConsult.Columns("a:b").AutoFit


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.